# Java - Why is InputStream#read designed in C style?

Tags: java, api, io

Since Java support exception, I thought an `EOFException` would be thrown when trying reading a byte at the end of an input stream, like

`byte read() throws EOFException, IOException`

But in fact [InputStream#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) returns

> the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.

which reminds me about `getchar` in C. But on the other hand it throws

> `IOException`: if an I/O error occurs.

Why is it designed in such way?

Comment: Many low level calls, just call the underlying C method and given more developers knew C at the time it made migration easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of the early APIs were less than desirable and there is plenty of discussion in which the designers wish they could have done it different.

I would speculate that this is not one of those cases. Throwing an "EOFException" would probably encourage programmers to `try` to read until an exception is caught. Meaning exception handling would be used as a way of controlling program logic which is referred to as the exception handling antipattern

Comment: It is true that exceptions are not meant for control flow but the reason for `EOFException` is to provide an escape hatch in corner cases where requirements make other approaches too difficult. One example is [DataInputStream.readFully()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5b%5d%29).

Answer (score 4):

It is designed that way because reaching `EOF` is **usually** not an exceptional event.

According to official [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html):

> An exception is an event that occurs during the execution of a program
>   that disrupts the normal flow of instructions.

So most of the time returning `EOF` is perfectly fine.

However, there are cases where throwing an exception just makes more sense. For example, `DataInputStream` class has a method called [`readFully`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5b%5d%29) which throws:

> EOFException - if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.

In short, an `EOFException` signifies a disruptive event while `EOF` gets returned during the normal flow of instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, one should ask himself if when reading the stream in a "normal" fashion, reaching end of file should be considered an exception. 
An exception comes to let us know that there is an exceptional wrong behavior at our application, this is not the case.
If you look at the javadoc of [EOFException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) you will see, and I quote -

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.

Please notice the "unexpectedly word, and the reservation this javadoc has at the next sentence.